# RabbitMQ - install for all users

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang

I am setting up a windows server 2022, with newest available RabbitMQ and Erlang OTP installed.

I can install it fine, no issues there.
But when other admins, want to use rabbitMQ, they cannot.
the admins accessing Rabbit, are all domain admins and local admins

The issue is, that it will ONLY run and accept commands, from the user that installed it.
you can not log in to rabbit, from any other user.

Is this something any of you know a way around?

3 admins, spend the better part of 3 days googling, and reloading server template, for fresh installs of Windows and being able to install rabbitMQ

Answer (score 2):

You don't give enough information to definitively diagnose the issue, but I can *guess* what is going on. When you report an issue with any software, at the minimum you should include the following information:

- Software versions
- Configuration
- A complete transcript of the commands you are running and the output shown
- Log files

> But when other admins, want to use rabbitMQ, they cannot. the admins accessing Rabbit, are all domain admins and local admins. The issue is, that it will ONLY run and accept commands, from the user that installed it. you can not log in to rabbit, from any other user.

I am assuming that by "run and accept commands" that you mean running the `rabbitmqctl.bat`, `rabbitmq-plugins.bat`, etc commands.

I assume that when you run one of those commands as a user other than the one that installed RabbitMQ, you get an error message. It would have been helpful to see that message, but it's probably something like this:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@bakkenl-z01'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@bakkenl-z01
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@bakkenl-z01']

rabbit@bakkenl-z01:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on bakkenl-z01
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie is identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
  * suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
  * suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
   * suggestion: see the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-344-rabbit@bakkenl-z01'
 * effective user's home directory: c:/Users/bakkenl
 * Erlang cookie hash: jhLS9kOjafo57g5JmVFgbQ==
```

The output gives you quite a bit of information about what could be going on. This is the relevant line:

> - CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)

The Erlang VM uses a "cookie" file to authenticate connections to it. When you install and start RabbitMQ, a cookie file is created in the Local System account's profile directory, which is usually `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie` (documented [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cli.html#erlang-cookie)).

You should copy that file to the home directory of every user who wishes to use `rabbitmqctl.bat` and other commands to manage RabbitMQ. If you continue to get errors like the one I provided above, double-check that you copied the file exactly. A checksum is the best way to confirm:

```
> Get-FileHash -Path .\.erlang.cookie -Algorithm SHA256

Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          00939061A448E102D386FF0D9F05910356B352322A446C5169AB3687E8C970E4       C:\Users\bakkenl\.erlang.cookie
```

If you continue to have issues, please provide all of the necessary information and post your question to one of the the official free support channels for RabbitMQ:

- https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions

Comment: Thanks for all the info here.. 

to take it from the top down. 

Versions: 
Erlang / OTP - 25.3(13.2)
RabbitMQ server - 3.11.13

The issue already arises, when installing the service. 
If i install it using, user A - no other user are able to connect or run any commands. 
They are not even able to run the CMD for the rabbitmq. 


but will try the things you suggest here, and see if it gets us any further :)